# How do I find a warped forest in the Nether?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I am not able to find a warped forest in the nether. I searched for a week with about 10 hours of gameplay. How can I find one?

Answer (score 2):

**Before you start searching, make sure you're on v1.16 of Minecraft**. Warped forests weren't available before then. If, after the upgrade to v1.16, you decide to play on a map you created before the upgrade, **you'll need to visit a part of the nether you've never been to before**. The game won't regenerate areas you've already discovered - they'll continue to be the old, generic nether biome.

At this point, **if you're not willing to use third-party tools, you have to keep searching**. There game doesn't provide you any clues where biomes are ahead of time.

**If you're willing to use third-party tools, try [ChunkBase's Biome Finder](https://www.chunkbase.com/apps/biome-finder#-46777102)**.

[image: picture of Biome Finder on ChunkBase]

**Make sure you do the following:**

- Get your map seed from your settings page and add it in the *Seed* field.
- For *Version*, select "Bedrock 1.14 and above", since you're on Bedrock.
- Below the map, select "The Nether" in the *Dimension* dropdown.

You can use "Filter Biomes" to only show certain biomes. However, once you've selected "The Nether" as your dimension, it's pretty easy to spot **the green areas that mark warped forests**. Mose your mouse cursor over one of those areas, and the coordinates for that spot will appear under the map.

If your coordinates aren't already showing in Minecraft in the upper left part of your screen, go to Settings, then the Game section. Scroll down until you see "Show Coordinates", and turn it on. You'll kow it's on if the slider bar is on the right side of the box.

Comment: Okay but i am on mcpe 1.16 beta and i have searched for third party apps and they are not for android

Comment: I am going to scearch like this... ⊙_⊙

Comment: @MKX Chunkbase does work on Android devices, as it's a website, no downloads or installs are needed to use it.

Comment: @MKX Let us know if using ChunkBase's website helped you find a warped forest! If so, don't forget to accept this answer so others with this problem can quickly find a solution. :)

Comment: Okay well chunkybase worked well i found a warped forest but it is like an island in the nether covered with 100 of lava block in length and many ghasts i will have to make a ghast proof bridge